# no se encontró el identificador C++

Tags: c++

Vengo de java y quiero aprender c++, en java solia hacer un método para ingresar opciones numéricas (utilizaba para menú) y solo retornaba cuando arroja un numero valido (mediante un try y catch).

bueno trate de simplificar el código hasta el punto que necesito ayuda, el código es este:

(ojo en realidad la idea es que returnOpcion() retorne un numero distinto de -1 xd, pero eso ya lo tengo solucionado, el drama que tengo es que cuando ejecuto ese codigo arroja : **'returnOpcion': no se encontró el identificador**)

```
int verificadorIngreso(int max) {
    int dato = -1;
    while (dato == -1) {
        dato = int(returnOpcion());
        getchar();
    }
    return dato;
}

int returnOpcion() {
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: En C++ la declaración de una función, clase, etc debe estar antes de su uso. En tu caso `returnOpcion` esta declarado despues de su uso, asi que hay 2 opciones: 1) mueve la función `returnOpcion` antes de `verificadorIngreso` o 2) añade `int returnOpcion();` antes de `verificadorIngreso`.

Comment: Eso explica Mucho :D, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El lenguaje C++ permite separar funciones y objetos en dos partes<sup>1</sup>:

- **Declaración**: Anuncias que el elemento existe, pero no entras en detalles de cómo es.
- **Definición**: Describes el elemento al detalle, cuenta como declaración si no estaba previamente declarado.

Si usas algo antes de que sea definido vas a tener un error como el que describes. Así que una posible solución es definir-usar-declarar:

```
int returnOpcion(); // Defino 'returnOpcion'

int verificadorIngreso(int max) {
    int dato = -1;
    while (dato == -1) {
        dato = int(returnOpcion()); // Uso 'returnOpcion'
        getchar();
    }
    return dato;
}

int returnOpcion() { // Declaro 'returnOpcion'
    return -1;
}
```

Y otra posible solución es declarar antes de usar:

```
int returnOpcion() { // Declaro 'returnOpcion'
    return -1;
}

int verificadorIngreso(int max) {
    int dato = -1;
    while (dato == -1) {
        dato = int(returnOpcion()); // Uso 'returnOpcion'
        getchar();
    }
    return dato;
}
```

---

<sup>1</sup>Esto habitualmente se hace en archivos de cabecera y archivos de código; Java sólo tiene archivos de código.

Answer (score 3):

Tus funciones son "free functions", no pertenecen a ninguna clase, así que si quieres usar una función declarada después del lugar donde la estás utilizando, tienes que poner la declaración arriba de la definición de `verificadorIngreso(int max)`, en este caso `int returnOpcion();`

Si fueran parte de una clase, como en Java, no habría problema. Por ejemplo:

```
struct clase
{
    int verificadorIngreso(int max) {
        int dato = -1;
        while (dato == -1) {
            dato = int(returnOpcion());
            getchar();
        }
        return dato;
    }

    int returnOpcion() {
        return -1;
    }
};
```